# Por que consigo cancelar o evento onkeydown mas não consigo cancelar o onkeyup?

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

Abaixo tenho dois campos usando a mesma função. No primeiro campo uso o `onkeydown` e no segundo `onkeyup`:

```js
function eventos(e){
   if(isNaN(e.key)){
      e.preventDefault();
      return;
   }
   console.log("Um número foi digitado");
}

document.getElementById("campo1").onkeydown = eventos;
document.getElementById("campo2").onkeyup = eventos;
```

```html
Digite apenas números (evento keydown):
<br>
<input id="campo1">
<br><br>
Digite apenas números (evento keyup):
<br>
<input id="campo2">
```

Na função eu verifico se o que foi digitado é um número com `isNaN(e.key)`. Se o que foi digitado não for um número, irá entrar no `if`, cancelar o evento e sair da função (`return`). Porém, apenas no evento `onkeydown`, caso seja digitado qualquer tecla que não seja um número, o evento é cancelado normalmente e nada acontece no input. Mas no evento `onkeyup`, se eu digitar uma letra, por exemplo, a letra é inserida no input.

Gostaria de saber o porquê do `preventDefault()` funcionar em um e não funcionar no outro evento.

[Pesquisei no MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/keyup_event) e lá diz que o evento `keyup` é cancelável.

Comment: Acho que é como a API do JS funciona, o value é inputado no keydown, no keyup não adianta validar, pq a entrada do dado foi no keydown. pelo meu entender das coisas o dado é inputado no "press", não no "release" então como vc vai validar se é número se já houve a entrada do dado... Eu não tenho certeza do que estou falando, mas é o que aparenta olhando como leigo no assunto

Comment: Humm... faz sentido e acendeu uma luzinha no fim do túnel.

Comment: É tipo vc levar um tiro e depois colocar o colete, vc tem que colocar o colete antes do tiro vir. Vc tem que validar antes da bala entrar, não depois que ela já entrou...:D

Comment: Realmente faz mt sentido isso que falou.

Comment: O evento é cancelado, tanto que o `console.log` não é mostrado, mas isso não retira os carateres que já lá estão.

Comment: @Isac não entra no console por causa do `return`. Ou seja, no evento keyup, tanto faz o preventDefault() estar lá ou não.

Comment: O cancelar do evento pode servir em efeitos de *bubbling* do evento, em que ele é cancelado e outros elementos já não o capturam, mas não para eliminar conteúdo do campo. Mas só confirmando na fonte mesmo.

Answer (score 4):

Não é que o `keyup` não pode ser cancelado, mas quem trata que foi pressionada uma tecla é o `keydown`, uma vez que não cancelou o `keydown` isso não pode mais ser feito, e o que foi digitado já está no input.

O evento `keyup` é mais um evento de notificação, para avisar que a tecla que foi pressionada agora foi liberada. É executado após o `keydown` e `keypress`, e ele não pode desfazer o que foi feito nesses outros eventos.

Parece meio inútil, mas imagine um jogo, em que a tecla de tiro seja "espaço", no `keypress` do espaço dispara um tiro e continua atirando, até que o evento `keyup` aconteça, daí pode disparar uma função que faça algo, como "carregar mais tiros", só um exemplo pra pensa na funcionalidade desse evento.

Veja pelo log que o evento é cancelado, mas nada muda no input, pois o `keydown` não foi cancelado:

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
    if (typeof event.cancelable !== 'boolean' || event.cancelable) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('evento cancelado, keydown');
    } else {
         console.warn('evento não pode ser cancelado, keydown');
    }
});

document.addEventListener('keyup', event => {
    if (typeof event.cancelable !== 'boolean' || event.cancelable) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('evento cancelado keyup');
    } else {
        console.warn('evento não pode ser cancelado keyup');
    }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="teste" />
```

Comment: Mt boa a explicação. Obg!